# Mock chained methods using EasyMock

Tags: java, easymock

How do you mock a chained method call in EasyMock? I have a chained method call:

```
srvc.getServiceManager().getDetails(Integer.parseInt(msgId));
```

I've tried to do

```
expect(srvc.getServiceManager().getDetails(Integer.parseInt(msgId)))
  .andReturn((String) notNull());
```

This throws a `NullPointerException.`

Trying to break this into two expectations also does not work. In that case I get

> matcher calls were used outside expectations

How do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Breaking into two expectations is perfectly fine, something like below:

```
final Service mockService = createMock(Service.class);
final ServiceManager mockServiceManager = createMock(ServiceManager.class);

final Capture<Integer> capturedMsgId = new Capture<Integer>();

expect(mockService.getServiceManager()).andReturn(mockServiceManager);
expect(mockServiceManager.getDetails(capture(capturedMsgId))).andReturn("someString");
```

You shouldn't get any exception about it.